# How end user select Dock, Anchor, Location,

Tags: c#, properties, anchor, dock

Im creating a program that get properties like size, location, dock, anchor, ... from user. for setting these properties in another project.

so is there any component that I use for this purpose? when I want to get size, I used a text box and checked the value is true or not (is seprate by , or not). and same for getting location.

but I dont know how to get Dock and Anchor from user. I should use something like combobox for select "Top", "Bottom", .. or any union of them...

is there any better way?

and also I want to show user the preview of selected properties. 
I should create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
dockStyleComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (DockStyle));
dockStyleComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += OnDockStyleChanged;

anchorStyleComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (AnchorStyles));

private void OnDockStyleChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   dockStyleComboBox.Dock = (DockStyle)dockStyleComboBox.SelectedItem;
}
```